# UITableView Custom Cell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

My program keeps crashing in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method when I am trying to create a custom table cell. I have put a breakpoint on each line in the code, and the code fails after I try creating the cell variable with the **error:** `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value`. I have used custom table cells successfully many times before and have not run into this issue. It seems simple but I can't figure out what is wrong. Perhaps something in xcode changed that I'm unaware of? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!... Also, I did in fact register my custom cell in `viewDidLoad`. I'll include that code as well.

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "FeedTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "feedCell")
```

**Probem Code Below:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

    cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Testing the description label of my cell."

    return cell
}
```

**Update**

The one difference between this project and others that have worked is that Xcode is now prompting me to put a bang (!) after as, whereas before I never used one. If I don't add (!) it gives me the error message "AnyObject is not convertible to `FeedTableViewCell`"

as! `FeedTableViewCell` -instead of- as `FeedTableViewCell`

**FeedTableViewCell Class**

```
import UIKit

class FeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        priceLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30.0)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is it crashing on? Is `descriptionLabel` nil?

Comment: it's crashing on 
    var cell:FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeue etc.....

Comment: I removed desciptionLabel all together and it still crashes on the var cell:FeedTableViewCell line.

Comment: And you're sure that your nib is set up correctly to return an instance of `FeedTableViewCell`? Can you change it to `as! UITableViewCell` and see if it still crashes?

Comment: it works with a plain prototype uitableviewcell, so for some reason it's not accepting my custom cell

Comment: You mean it works when you cast it to `UITableViewCell` still using your nib? If so, make sure you change the class of the top-level view in your nib file to `FeedTableViewCell`

Comment: Is the class of the cell in your xib set to FeedTableViewCell? Is it a subclass of UITableViewCell?

Comment: @dan it works using a plain prototype tableviewcell not while using my nib.

Comment: @rdelmar the class of my xib is set to FeedTableViewCell and its subclass is UITableViewCell

Comment: @JRG-Developer I've done that tutorial before, thanks though. This isn't my first time working with table cells, that's the most frustrating part. I've gotten it to work many times before.

Comment: (I deleted this comment, but since you responded to it, I'll add it back :] try this tutorial:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift It shows several examples of how to do this. If you run into problems / have a specific issue, update your question with such.

Comment: Regarding, `The one difference between this project and others that have worked is that Xcode is now prompting me to put a bang (!) after as`, this is due to changes in Swift 1.3, which requires explicitly putting `as?` or `as!`. I wouldn't think this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't think so either, I just included that because it's the only noticeable difference between what I got to work previous and what is failing to work now

Comment: Can you verify that the `target membership` of the `xib` is correct? It's under `File Inspector` (top-right corner, click button to `hide or show utilities` -> first tab that looks like a page icon -> verify that your app/library target is correctly checked)

Comment: This is just in a normal app- not a static library or dynamic framework, right?

Comment: Yes, just a normal app. The target library is correct... I'm at the point where I'm considering blowing it up and starting over

Comment: Is the `descriptionLabel` outlet set correctly? That error is suspiciously ambiguous.

Comment: Never mind... sounds like you've stepped through this with breakpoints already...I imagine you would have pin pointed the line causing this error by doing such.

Comment: Yeah I put breakpoints everywhere, even in methods where I didn't suspect an issue because I was so paranoid

Comment: Sigh, this is too generic to simply guess. Nuke it! Try setting it up again, and see if it works (maybe not the entire project, but just the cell to start). Good luck. :]

Comment: Here's a curve ball, I just created an entirely new custom table cell, set it up the exact same way, and now it works..... I have no idea what in the hell went wrong with the first one, but this was a nightmare. Thanks for your suggestions! I'll keep me fingers crossed that this stays working

Answer (score 6):

After spending way too much time trying to get it to work. I nuked my custom table cell, created a brand new one, set it up the exact same way, and everything is working fine now. Still have no idea what happened, but I guess the lesson from this is that sometimes you just have to nuke it and start over.

Answer (score 0):

you should used like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedTableViewCell


    cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Testing the description label of my cell."

    return cell
}
```

for more help used this link http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/01/17/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/

Comment: The problem is, xcode is prompting me to add the bang ( ! ) operator for optional unwrapping after " as " in the variable declaration. It gives me an error without it.

Comment: this problem is happen in my code also? i have change the your code

Comment: -1:  The `as!` is due to new Swift syntax changes in version 1.3. You must include it if you're using Xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.3. This very likely isn't the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
var cell:FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell",) as! FeedTableViewCell
```

`NSIndexPath` may make this issue.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: unfortunately that did not work :/ .... I have used NSIndexPath before in many other projects as well, and it has never given me an issue before. Thanks for trying none the less!

Comment: Have you checked the identifier in Nib file as `feedCell`?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it many times, haha... I included a change I noticed between this and other projects I've worked on up above

Comment: Last thing which may get problem is define nib class, like `var nib = UINib(nibName: "FeedTableViewCell", bundle: nil) as! FeedTableViewCell` 
            `tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "feedCell")`

Comment: it will not allow my execute a command like that. I get a lot of errors

Comment: -1: specifying index path should not cause this issue. Rather, you should prefer using it as it actually helps the table view layout the cells correctly.